# azure remote app does not run properly Using access runtime

Tags: azure, runtime, remoteapp

I set up remoteapp properly but the result is that the app only half works
Front end is access runtime 2002 front end sql express back end

some records do open but most of the time I get the error-'could not delete from specified table'

The app worked perfectly before setting it up as a remote app.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a better audience for this question is https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=azureremoteapp